# python call function from another class

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt4

i just want to ask how would i access or call the function from another class?

sample code:

```
Class OpenOMX(QtCore.QThread):
    def __init__(self):
       QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
    def run(self):
       'Statment here'
    def PlayPause(self):
       'Statment here'
Class VidPlayer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
       QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
    def setupUI(self,MainWindow):
       'Statement here'
    def retranslateUI(self,MainWindow):
       self.btnPause.clicked.connect(OpenOMX.PlayPause)
```

i got an error saying:

```
TypeError: unbound method PlayPause() must be called with OpenOMX instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is not safe to directly call methods in the main GUI thread from a worker thread, or vice versa. Instead, you should always use [signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html):

```
class OpenOMX(QtCore.QThread):
    statusChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def PlayPause(self):
       'Statment here'
       ...
       self.statusChanged.emit(status)

class VidPlayer(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        self.openOMX = OpenOMX()
        self.btnPause.clicked.connect(self.openOMX.PlayPause)
        self.openOMX.statusChanged.connect(self.handleStatusChanged)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def handleStatusChanged(self, status):
        print('status change:', status)
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the play `PlayPause` function is a method of the `OpenOMX` class. That means that Python expects to be called on an instance of that class, with code like `instance.PlayPause()`. If you access the method directly via the class instead (e.g. `OpenOMX.PlayPause`), you get an unbound method, which requires that you pass in an instance as an argument.

You're getting an error because the button you're setting to call `PlayPause` doesn't pass in an instance. And in the code you've shown, you never create a `OpenOMX` instance, so it's not clear where you'd find one to pass, even if you could.

I'm not sure where the right place to create an instance is in your code. Perhaps you're already doing so in the parts of your code that you've omitted. If not, you'll have to use your own judgement as to where it would be best to create one.

Anyway, once you have an `OpenOMX` instance, you can pass `PlayPause` to `connect` as a bound method with something like:

```
def retranslateUI(self, MainWindow):
    self.btnPause.clicked.connect(self.whatever_you_named_your_instance.PlayPause)
```

A bound method will pass the instance into the function automatically.

Comment: I've created an instance for the OpenOMX: